# Generics wildcard put and get rule

Tags: java, generics

I know that this way is impossible:

```
public abstract class TestChecker<T extends IHandler> extends Observable implements ITestChecker {}

public class MyTest extends TestChecker<FirstHandler> {}
public class SecondTest extends TestChecker<SecondHandler> {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends TestChecker<IHandler> > handlers = new ArrayList<TestChecker>();

    MyTest myTest = new MyTest();
    handlers.add(myTest);

    SecondTest secondTest = new SecondTest();
    handlers.add(secondTest);
}
```

As it's described in the rule:

> Use an extends wildcard when you only get values out of a structure,
>   use a super wildcard when you only put values into a structure, and
>   don't use a wildcard when you both get and put.
>
> exceptions are:
>
> You cannot put anything into a type declared with an EXTENDS wildcard
>   except for the value null, which belongs to every reference type
>
> you cannot get anything out from a type declared with an SUPER
>   wildcard except for a value of type Object, which is a super type of
>   every reference type

But i'm not sure i really get it, and why this seems to work:

```
List<? super TestChecker<? extends IHandler> > handlers = new ArrayList();
```

Thank you,
RoD

Comment: It "seems to work" because you have a raw `ArrayList` there. The compiler doesn't perform generic checks on raw types. You also have a raw `TestChecker` in your first code snippet. Also, can you elaborate on "I'm not sure I really get it"? Is there a particular part of PECS you don't understand? Is there something the other PECS questions don't answer adequately?

Comment: Well, what i don't really understand, is why, we can only choose if we gonna use the collection to add ( then use super ) or to get ( then use extends ) and we can't do both ... with the same list.

It just prevents from using generics ?

Comment: Um, I don't think I quite follow. You *can* do both with the same list; it just requires you that you use a *specific* type instead of using wildcards. Could you try to explain more?

Comment: indeed, dunno, i guess i was tired ! thank you for your help !